# CAPL script to analyze logging file

Tags: offline, capl

I"m using CANoe and a CAPL script to perform statistic on CAN Frame.
I want to do that in offline mode playing a log file. In offline mode, I want to Start a replay file (.blf) from CAPL program and perform test on CAN frame (such as cycle time violation).
But when I try to use CAPL Function StartReplayFile in a Program Node I got an error:
Error     1159 at (76,26): function is not allowed within the current context (CANalyzer, Analyze, Test ...).   Offline_Config.can

I tried to use this function in other context but I never succeed to startReplayfile using CAPL.
So, How to use this function? How to start Replay file from CAPL and perform statistic analysis on log file using CAPL?
Many thanks for your support

I tried to use StartReplay file in CAPL in Simulation Setup but it's only available in online mode.
I tried to startreplayfile in Program node but I got an error

Comment: Can't you use online mode and the simulated bus and then put your code into a node in simulation setup?

Answer (score 0):

In CANoe you have two setups: (1) Simulation Setup and (2) Measurement Setup.

I've done this before loading my Log.blf file in my "Measurement Setup" setting it as "Offline Modus" instead of doing it in a Replay Block in the "Simulation Setup".
Afterwards, when you get your data over the virtual bus of CANoe, then you use a i.e. a Network Node in your "Simulation Setup" with your Statistical Analisis code in CAPL.